# Not getting results from mysql using query in views in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using MySQL database which and try to filter data according to date but while using filter I am getting nothing.While i uncomment this line

> print(searchresult.Date)

then it will show error 500.

Here is my view.py

```
from sales.model import Mar21

def show(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromdate = request.POST.get('startdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        # date = Mar21.objects.only('Date')
        print(fromdate)
        print(todate)
        searchresult = Mar21.objects.filter(date__lte = fromdate,date__gte = todate)
        # print(searchresult.Date)
        return render(request,'front.html',{'data':searchresult})  
    else:
        data = Mar21.objects.all()   
        # print(data)
        return render(request,"front.html",{'data':data})
```

Here is my model

```
from django.db import models


class Mar21(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    date = models.DateField(db_column='Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sales_channel = models.TextField(db_column='Sales Channel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    sales_order_id = models.FloatField(db_column='Sales order ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    ship_to_name = models.TextField(db_column='Ship to name', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    sku = models.TextField(db_column='SKU', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    normal_sku = models.TextField(db_column='Normal SKU', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    vendor = models.TextField(db_column='Vendor', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    quantity = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='Quantity', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    line_total = models.FloatField(db_column='Line Total', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    channel_order_id = models.TextField(db_column='channel order id', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mar21'
```

and here is my html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sales Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                From :<input type="date" name="startdate"/>
                To :<input type="date" name="todate"/>
                <input type="submit" name="search">
            
                <hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
```

Comment: `Mar21.objects.filter(...)` will give you a queryset (a collection of `Mar21` instances) not one `Mar21` instance. (Furthermore your model doesn't have a field named `Date`, it is named `date`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your filter, since the expression fromdate <= DATE and todate >= DATE a is a logical error

In that sense, I recommend you do it this way.

```py
searchresult = Mar21.objects.filter(date__range=(from_date, to_date))

# or you can reverse your filter
searchresult = Mar21.objects.filter(date__gte=from_date, date__lte=to_date)

# or use an expression
from django.db.models import Q
searchresult = Mar21.objects.filter(Q(date__gte=from_date) & Q(date__lte=to_date))
```